# Bulk search and replace

Tags: windows-7, find-and-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bulk search and replace](https://superuser.com/questions/371305/bulk-search-and-replace)

I have more than 1000 php files.

I need to BULK search and replace a text.

I want to search and replace both file content and filenames.

Is there any script or software available to do that?

PS: I use windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about file names, but Notepad++ should help you with bulk find/replace in files:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/notepadpp-tricks.html (Step 2)

A quick google for bulk file renamer provided a few results that look good.