# Bulk search and replace

Tags: search

I have more than 1000 php files.

I need to BULK search and replace a text.

I want to serach and replace both file content and filenames.

Is there any script or software available to do that?

Comment: I use windows 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for find and replace file contents

Comment: Does notepad++ let you search and replace all files in an entire directory tree?

Comment: yes, you can find and replace text in files in a directory ( and all sub directories)

Answer (score 3):

Try [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/), although you have to open the files, you can open all at once. Global find and replace works very fast.

You can also try [Replacer](http://www.simonhuggins.com/arctan/replacer/index.html)